# Continuous Dependence on Regularization Constant

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In machine learning, many models end up with formulating an optimization problem like $L(x) + \lambda R(x)$ where $L(x)$ is a loss function and $R(x)$ is a regularization function. Let's say both $L(x)$ and $R(x)$ have nice regularity and they are convex, is it true that $x^\star(\lambda) = argmin_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{L(x) + \lambda R(x)\}$ depends continuously on $\lambda$? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: A linear loss function doesn't make any sense- are you perhaps interested in convex quadratic loss function or an $L_{1}$ loss function?

Comment: @BrianBorchers you are right, a linear loss function doesn't make sense for practical machine learning problems. Here I am more interested in understanding the continuous dependence of minimizer w.r.t regularization constant, no matter what loss function is used. Thanks for pointing it out, though. I will correct my question.